# Why is this the probability of getting r streaks when flipping a coin n times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I flip a coin *n* times. I define number of streaks *r* as the number of times that the coin changes sides plus 1. So, for example, if I flip the coin 5 times and I get HHHTH, that would be 3 strikes (*r* = 3). If I get TTTTT that would be *r* = 1.

My text book states that the probability of getting *r* streaks is:

$$
P\lbrace X = r\rbrace = \binom{n-1}{r-1}·\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}
$$

I can't see why. Could someone explain it?

Thank you!

Comment: The probability of any toss (after the first one) representing a change is $\frac 12$.

Comment: The first streak begins with the first flip.  From that point on, rather than keeping track of the coins by referring to if they are Heads versus Tails... refer to them as either Continuing the current streak or Starting a new streak.  So for instance, with H as heads, T as tails, C as continuing a streak and N as starting a new streak, the sequence `HTTHHH` corresponds to the sequence `HNCNCC` and the sequence `TTTTTT` corresponds to the sequence `TCCCCC`.  You should be able to see that every sequence of `N`'s and `C`'s are equally likely and getting $r$ streaks corresponds to $r-1$ `N`'s

Comment: So, to count them... from the $n-1$ positions after the first, choose which $r-1$ of those positions correspond to starting a new streak.  Divide by $2^{n-1}$ since each of the $2^{n-1}$ possible sequences of continuing or starting a new streak after the initial flip are equally likely to get the probability.

Comment: Aaah great I see it now. Thanks!